# C++ writing to file producing garbage data

Tags: c++

I am trying to add data into a text file. However, i see for some reason it produces garbage data. I also notice, it will input the correct data once, but then it follow with garbage data.

```
 void TextFileLogger::log(std::string msg){
        using namespace std;
        //ofstream output_file("students.data", ios::binary);
        std::ofstream logFile;
        // creating, opening and writing/appending data to a file
        char filename[] = "log.txt";
        logFile.open(filename, ios::binary | ios::app |ios::out);

        if (logFile.fail())
        {
            std::cout << "The " << filename << " file could not be created/opened!" << std::endl;
            // 0-normal, non zero - some errors
        }
        else
        {
            if (!logFile.write((char*)&msg, sizeof(msg)))
            {
                cout << "Could not write file" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                streamsize bytesWritten = logFile.tellp();
                if (bytesWritten != sizeof(msg))
                {
                    cout << "Could not write expected number of bytes" << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    logFile << msg << std::endl;
                    cout << "file written OK" << endl;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This also happens when the file does not exist or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That one is fun!

`(char*)&msg` does not do what you expect: `std::string` is mainly a pointer to a dynamically-allocated buffer which contains the actual data. When you take the `std::string`'s address and try to read what's inside, you get a view of its innards, not its data. Using a C++ `static_cast` here would have spared you the trouble by telling you that the conversion makes no sense. `sizeof(msg)` similarly returns the size of the `std::string`, not the length of its data.

So, your solution is: use `msg.data()` and `msg.size()`, it's exactly what they're designed for.

But... why would it (sometimes) output your string, and a bunch of garbage? Well, `std::string`s typically use SSO (Small String Optimization). The `std::string` actually contains a small buffer, to store short enough strings without dynamic allocation. When you inspect the whole `std::string` object, you see this buffer pass by.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the contents of the whole std::string object, with all the member variables that it contains internally.
You either want:

```
logFile << msg;
```

or if you really want to use `write()`:

```
logFile.write( msg.c_str(), msg.length());
```

And, I wonder: Why do create/open the file in binary mode, when you write strings afterwards?
And finally, you write the data twice, the second time in your last else clause.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
if (!logFile.write((char*)&msg, sizeof(msg)))
```

It should be this:

```
if (!logFile.write(msg.c_str(), msg.length()))
```

Since you are passing a **std::string** into the function, you should take advantage of the functions it provides (**c_str()** and **length()**) instead of trying to cast it to a char* (this always gets messy, plus you are casting away the const, which is also typically bad).

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
  if (!logFile.write((char*)&msg, sizeof(msg)))
```

is wrong in so many ways. `msg` is not an array of char, it's a std::string - lying to the compiler by using a cast is always a bad thing to do. And the size of a string is *not* the size of the characters it contains. Why the heck are you not using the obvios:

```
 logfile << msg << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `sizeof(msg)` with `msg.size()`, sizeof() is not doing what you think!

Also `(char*)&msg` does not do whatever you think, use msg.data() instead.

```
logFile.write((char*)&msg, sizeof(msg));
```

should be rewritten to:

```
logFile.write(msg.data(), msg.size());
```

or, even better, because ofstream overrides operator<< for std::string:

```
logfile << msg;
```